# Get Enum name from the display attribute in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an enumeration

```
public enum GTMType
        {
            [Display(Name = "CHANNEL_CHANNEL")]
            ChannelChannel,
            [Display(Name = "CHANNEL_WHOLESALE")]
            ChannelWholesale,
            [Display(Name = "ENTERPRISE_DIRECT")]
            EnterpriseDirect,
            [Display(Name = "ENTERPRISE_AGENT")]
            EnterpriseAgent,
            [Display(Name = "ENTERPRISE_SYSTEM_INTEGRATOR")]
            EnterpriseSystemIntegrator
        }
```

when I make an API call to another system to get data, The system returns the value which is a display attribute value.

```
public Account GetDataForAccountByID(string id)
{
  AccountModel accountModel = GetDataFromAnotherSystem(id);
 //after the call is successfull accountModel looks like 
 //{Email: "abc@xyz.com",GTMType:"CHANNEL_CHANNEL"}

 var account = new Account
 {
   EmailAddress: = accountModel.Email,
   GTMType = accountModel.GTMType

 };

}

public class AccountModel
{
public string Email { get; set; }
public string GTMType { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public GTMType GTMType { get; set; 
 }
```

How can I convert the string value which is of display attribute value can be converted into an enum.

Comment: Why is `AccountModel.GTMType` defined as `string` and not as `GTMType`?

Comment: if it is defined as enumeration than the data which comes from another system in  JSON will have to be converted by a custom parser.  so it is string

Comment: I don't understand the usecase. I have seen people wanting to get Display name from Enum Value or Index. Can you elaborate? Plus how are you getting Display Name, there you can get the value too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enum.GetValues` to iterate over possible values of the enum and then `GetField` representing the given value and get its attributes.

```
GTMType ParseGTMTypeFromAnotherSystem(string gtmType)
{
    var type = typeof(GTMType);

    foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(type))
    {
        var fieldInfo = type.GetField(Enum.GetName(type, value));
        DisplayAttribute[] attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) as DisplayAttribute[];
        if (attributes.Length != 1)
        {
            throw new Exception("Enum definition is wrong.");
        }

        var displayName = attributes[0].Name;
        if (gtmType == displayName)
        {
            return value as GTMType;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Unable to parse.");
}
```

You may want to handle the exception cases differently, e.g. iterate over all DisplayAttributes in case there's more than one and ignore fields that have none, or in case of a failed parse return a default value - depends on your use case.